# Regexp that convert markdown tables to textile ones

Tags: regex, markdown, textile

I'd like to convert markdown tables in textile one.

Markdown tables follow this pattern:

```
| column | column |
|--------|--------|
|        |        |
```

While textile this one:

```
|_.column |_.column |
|         |         |
```

Now I wrote the following expression:

```
text.gsub(/\|[-|]+/, '')
```

That remove the `|--------|` bars.
I'd like also to add the `_.` before every column title, in order to make them bold.

Do you have any idea for obtaining this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know ruby at all, hence can't be sure of anything about its own syntaxic aspects. So here is a *Javascript* proposed solution, hopefully it's known widely enough to be easily transposed:

```
function markdown2textileTables(source) {
  var lines = source.split('\n');
  lines.forEach(function(line, index, lines) {
    if (!!line.match(/^\|(?:[-]+\|)+$/)) {
      var prevLineCols = lines[index - 1].split('|');
      prevLineCols = prevLineCols.map(function(col) {
        return !!col ? '_.' + col.trim() : col;
      });
      lines[index - 1] = prevLineCols.join('|');
      lines.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  return lines.join('\n');
}
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aunuwr5L/).

Note that I didn't take care of title columns length when changing from `|  column  |` to `|_.column|`, because I don't know if it matters or not.
If yes, the above code would need to be improved at the `return !!col ? '_.' + col.trim() : col;` statement, depending on current `col.length` and either adding spaces or cutting title.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/README.html):

```
pandoc mytable.md -t textile -o mytable.textile
```